# Не переведена строка выпадающего меню на странице контактов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[Страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact).
Скрин:

[image: I need help with Careers/Jobs]

Строка «I need help with Careers/Jobs».

Можно ещё заменить `отклонен` на `отклонён`, раз уж в словах `учётную` и `учётные` проставлены точки над ё.

Comment: Вероятно, этот пункт надо **вообще убрать**, потому что филиала SO.Careers у нас пока нет.

Comment: На первое время добавил перевод «Мне нужна помощь с Карьерой/Вакансиями». На самом деле, для Careers и Jobs переводов сообщество еще не выбирало. Использую те термины, которые были на [ХэшКод Карьере](http://careers.hashcode.ru).